# Why does fieldspcified creats in WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have created a web service using WCF. Then I exposed it as a web service to make it usable with a .NET 4.0 application. I created some DataContract with DataMember

```
    **[DataMember]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }**
```

If I used IsRequired filed as true in DataMember  my application working fine.

```
    **[DataMember (IsRequired=true)]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }**
```

If I not used isRequired field its throwing error also its generating below field specified in my application.

**private int teamIdField;

private bool teamIdFieldSpecified;**

My application not working and its returning value as 0 instead of Team ID value.so that I’m getting foreign key conflict error message too.

Is there any other way to fix that above Error?

Comment: why should i set IsRequired=true for all the int datatype column

Comment: Hello Team, any updates on my question ?